# How to remove Schema.org Microdata markup in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, schema.org, microdata

In any WooCommerce install, this plugin adds Schema.org markup to product pages via Microdata. Sadly, this info is not accurate, so I would like to add my own Schema.org markup via JSON-LD, but then I find the following problem: my Product markup is duplicated.

So I would like to remove the 'default' Microdata Schema.org markup from my WooCommerce site. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Probably override their templates with your own. See [templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). Though if there microdata is really wrong, you may want to submit a [bug report](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues)

Comment: The thing is that with JSON-LD I can add more properties (info) than those covered with 'default' markup.